# Making the ui elements resize when the window is resized

Tags: qt, user-interface, resize

I'm pretty new at using ui files on Qt. What i need to know is how i can make all the elements resize when the user resizes the window.

Comment: Reimplement the `resizeEvent` method in the window widget.

Answer (score 3):

To have automatically resizable widgets you should put them into layouts.
Have a look at [Qt Layout Management](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html) system.